# 2 sets of controls on one video?

Tags: wordpress, html5-video, video.js

can anyone advise what might be causing 2 sets of controls on this site please?

http://www.janequinn.biz/media/

Only started appearing after just updating the wordpress plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of video.js on that page and three versions of the video.js css.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='videojs-css'  href='//vjs.zencdn.net/4.5/video-js.css?ver=3.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video.js"></script>
```